# VSCode not using compile_commands.json for library paths

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-code, mingw-w64, msys

I've tried everything but I can't get VSCode to recognize my library paths inside `compile_commands.json`. Below are some pictures to show what I mean:

The project tree
[image: The project tree]

The actual files
[image: The actual files]

As you can see the C/C++ extension isn't detecting my libraries even though they are contained within my `compile_commands.json` that is generated by CMake. Any help with this would be really appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the [October 2017 update](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/10/20/visual-studio-code-cc-extension-october-2017-update/) or later?

Comment: I do. The extension, vscode, and cmake are all updated to their latest versions.

Answer (score 1):

The generator of your `compile_commands.json` file is moving the include paths into [response files](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Response_Files) files (the `@file.rsp` files in the text of the "command": field of your Json). Some generators will do this on Windows to limit the length of commands entered on the commands line, which is currently about ~8k characters, as compared to ~128k characters on Linux. Historically Windows had even shorter limits, so some tools proactively move everything into @files, even when the line lengths limits wouldn't be exceeded.

Unfortunately the `vscode-cpptools` extension doesn't currently process this `@file.rsp` syntax. See this [thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/1718).

Try using the Ninja generator when you call Cmake. For me (running mingw64 inside MSys2), Ninja created self-contained `compile_commands.json` files that vscode-cpptools parses correctly.

Example calling cmake from the root of the source directory:

```
$ cmake -H"." -B"${output_dir}" -G"Ninja" -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=1
```